# HTML putting clickable image inside ordered list

Tags: html, image

I got this dank photo of a fedora and I want it to be clicked on to go to this youtube video, but the click box is only the very left border.

HTML:

```
    <div id="left_Background" >
        <ul>
            <a href="https://youtu.be/T99j7bw9eWo?t=64">
                <img id = "fedora" src ="https://img.4plebs.org/boards/pol/image/1385/75/1385757943224.jpg" style = "width: 230px";/>
            </a>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

Css:

```
#left_Background {
    background-color: black;
    height:100%;
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    overflow: visible;
    right: auto !important; 
    position: fixed ;
    left: -20px;
    max-width: 250px;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

edit: formatting fixed

Comment: Could you post your HTML?

Comment: Trying adding `display:inline-block;` to the `<a>` tag.

Comment: I created a fiddle with the provided code and could not reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/469177qr/

Comment: I also can't reproduce it in JSFiddle. Do you have some other CSS affecting the HTML? Try checking using your browsers "Inspect Element" feature.

Comment: It would help if you post a screenshot of the desired effect against the current problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried floating the 'a' in the CSS so that it covers the whole of the image?

Answer (score 0):

You have a ul tag but no li tag inside.. Maybe try to start with this

Comment: just did that didn't do anything

Comment: Did you made the changes in the fiddle as we can see it ?